# How to create custom methods for sprite groups in pygame?

Tags: sprites, pygame, oop

I want to use sprite groups in my game using pygame and the default draw isn't enough. I have tried some tutorials but I failed.

So, being more specific: I want to create custom methods for sprite groups in pygame such as `.handle_event` (this method can exist at all sprites or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `pygame.sprite.Group` subclass and add the methods you need. If you want to customize and override the `draw` method ([which you can see here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/67026e3c51843d9313bbc8cc8a35d219eee3d4d4/lib/sprite.py#L464)), you have to copy the original method and then add your modifications to it.

```
class ExtendedGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):

    def handle_event(self, event):
        for spr in self.sprites():
            # Check if the sprite has a `handle_event` method.
            if hasattr(spr, 'handle_event'):
               spr.handle_event(event)

    def draw(self, surface):
        sprites = self.sprites()
        surface_blit = surface.blit
        for spr in sprites:
            self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
            # I've added this line which draws a rect.
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, SIENNA, (spr.rect.topleft, (15, 15)))
        self.lostsprites = []
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep track of sprite groups using attributes of my `Game` class, which contains my game loop.

For example, in the `new_game()` method of this class, I create groups in the following way:

```
    # create groups
    self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.projectiles = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.portals = pg.sprite.Group()
```

Each of these groups corresponds a class I created which inherits from Pygame's `Sprite` class. For example, here is a sketch of my `Mob` class.

```
class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.mobs
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)     # this will add any instance of this class to the game's mobs group  
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((64,64))            
        self.image.fill(RED)                            
        self.pos = vec(x,y)
        self.bounding_rect = pg.Rect((0,0),(64,64))     
        self.bounding_rect.center = self.pos

    def update():
        pass

    def draw():
        pass
```

Notice that in my initialization code, I add any instance of this class to my `mobs` group. Notice further that I allow myself to define `update()` and `draw()` methods for this class.

I do something similar with classes for projectiles, portals, etc. They all have their own group and can have their own `update()` and `draw()` methods.

If you structure things this way, you can then update and draw all your objects in your main game loop's `update()` and `draw()` methods like this:

```
def update(self):
   for mob in self.mobs:
       mob.update()
   for projectile in self.projectiles:
       projectile.update()
   ...

def draw(self):
   for mob in self.mobs:
       mob.draw()
   for projectile in self.projectiles:
       projectile.draw()
   ...
```

In this way, you can create custom `update()` and `draw()` methods for whatever objects your game requires.

Comment: Thank you! I liked this idea. Howerver, the below answer is what I was looking for.